# ASP.NET Identity always shows error "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, plesk

I created an ASP.NET MVC5 project with default template and individual user account authentication (identity).

I changed default connection string to connect my existing database that includes all tables necessary for identity.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=sa;Password=123456;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Everything works fine locally, but when I login identity in hosting, I get this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Then I tried again with a new project without identity, I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model connect to my existing database from my project and get some data to show in a view. It works fine locally and in my hosting environment.

Can someone please explain and help to fix error in case 1? Sorry my English is not good, thanks you so much.

Comment: You need to grant your user create database permissions. It appears somewhere in your app you are creating a database. This sound like a bug, search your code of any create db statements exist.

Comment: i had tried add: Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null); in identity constructor but no luck. I think something make identity context not detect database has been existed

Comment: Try opening up SQL management studio and browse your DB objects through there and confirm permissions.